# Django display list of ForeingKey relationship

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using django 2 and python 3.

In my model I have Users that can own a list of Applications. Applications can have only one Owner.
I used a ForeingKey like so:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # nothing interresting for this question here
    pass


class StoreApplication(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name="applications"
    )
```

Now I would like to list the User's applications in the User's admin page, like a list of application names, just readonly stuff. Not in the list view, in the edit view.

I'm aware of InlineModelAdmin and it does not seem to resolve my issue, as it includes the whole Application forms for each of the user's application.

If I try to reference the field as "applications" in my user admin:

```
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("username", )

    fieldsets = (
        ("Général", {
            "fields": ("username", "applications", )
        }),
    )
```

An error occurs:
`Unknown field(s) (applications) specified for User. Check fields/fieldsets/exclude attributes of class UserAdmin.`

Comment: Like with `ModelAdmin`, `InlineModelAdmin` can be customised to include only the fields you want (using `fields = ...`) and if you wish, only readonly fields, in exactly the same way. That's the only way to display all related models of a ManyToMany relationship (beside defining your own method, e.g. a method returning a comma-separated list of some value of the related model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a method to the UserAdmin that returns all the applications as a comma separated list. I'm going to assume there is a CharField on the StoreApplication model that names the object (name)

```py
def get_applications(self, obj):
    return ', '.join([app.name for app in obj.applications])

# set the short_description to how you want that field displayed in admin
get_applications.short_description = 'Applications'
```

Then just add get_applications to fields and readonly_fields